# How can I grab files from inside a parent directory and all subdirectories inside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, discord.js

I want to grab all javascript files inside the parent directory and in all sub directories for my discord.js command handler. How do I achieve that?

I have a working block of code that already grabs all .js files from the parent directory, but all sub directories are left alone.

```
const botConfig = require('./config/nvdconfig.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const prefix = botConfig.prefix;
// nvdColor: #45c263

const bot = new Discord.Client({
    disableEveryone: true
});

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const {
    readdirSync,
    statSync
} = require('fs');

const {
    join
} = require('path');

fs.readdir('./cmds/', (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js');
    if (jsfiles.length <= 0) {
        return console.log('No commands to load.');
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands!`);

    jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
        let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`);
        console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`);
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    });
});
```

I expect the same result from the loading of the jsfiles through the parent directory as well as all current and future subdirectories.

My current result is all js files are being loaded in but the ones inside the subdirectories are left alone.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this! Thank you in advance.

Comment: [search, and research](/help/how-to-ask) before hitting that "post" button. Just start smaller: Google/search Stackoverflow for "nodejs recursive list all files in directory". That _will_ get you results (including answers from this site), and will get you on your way to solving this all on your own, instead.

Comment: I have done that and nothing helped. I have figured it out on my own. I will post an answer to my question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to get the result that I want.
I found a node package called fs-readdir-recursive that had everything I wanted.
Install the package: `npm install fs-readdir-recursive --save`
And initialize it. `const <var name> = require('fs-readdir-recursive');`

Then after you do that, create another variable. `const <var name> = read('./<parent directory>/');`

This variable will be the parent directory that is searched through with a for each loop.

```
const <var name> = require('fs-readdir-recursive');
const files = read('./cmds/');
files.forEach(file => {
    let cmd = file.replace('.js', '');
    let props = require(`./cmds/${cmd}`);

    <your code here>

});
```

This will read each file in each directory of the parent.